# Cypress Assertion .should() fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, cypress

I want to use

```js
cy.getByTestId(testId)
        .should('have.attr', 'data-testStatus', 'OK')
        .and('have.attr', 'opacity', '0');
```

and
`cy.getByTestId(testId)` yields me this:

```js
<circle class="js-components-SvgFiles-SvgBearingBlock-___SvgBearingBlock__featureSelected___RhROg" 
cx="66.5" cy="66.5" r="29.925" stroke-width="0" opacity="0" data-testStatus="OK" data-testid="fixedBearing_Circle"></circle>
```

but I always get this error message:

```
expected <circle.js-components-SvgFiles-SvgBearingBlock-___SvgBearingBlock__featureSelected___RhROg> to have attribute data-testStatus
```

Why is `.should(` not using the outer html?

---

I've tested all your recommendations. Unfortunately always with the same result:

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhUlu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htoQ1.png)

That's the code written in React:

```
return (
    <svg className={cn(style.svg, className)} width={size} height={size}
         data-testid={blockType+'_'+( isLeftSide?'Left':'Right')} data-testStatus={testIdPlane}>
      {feature}
      {/* id of the bearing*/}
      <text
        className={colorText}
        x={textPos}
        y={size * 0.85}
        textAnchor="middle"
        fontSize={fontSize}
        fontWeight="bold"
      >
        {text}
      </text>
      {dummyText}
    </svg>
  );
```

Thats the 
[React Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgUO1.png)

And i just realized that stuff like this:

```
cy.getByTestId('slidingBearing_Line')
            .should('have.attr', 'opacity', '1')
            .and('have.attr', 'y')
            .should('gt', y);
```

is working

Comment: Isn'it possible with cypress to test directly the presence of data-attributes ? Like in `.should('have.data', 'testStatus', 'OK')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
cy.get('[data-testid="fixedBearing_Circle"]')
    .should('have.attr', 'data-testStatus', 'OK')
    .and('have.attr', 'opacity', '0');
```

ScreenShot:[image: Screenshot of the result]